# neo4j cypher taking time to set relationship

Tags: neo4j, set, relationship

I am relatively new to neo4j. 
I have imported dataset of 12 million records and I have created a relationship between two nodes. When I created the relationship, I forgot to attach a property to the relationship. Now I am trying to set the property for the relationship as follows.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///FileName.csv' AS row
MATCH (user:User{userID: USERID})
MATCH (order:Order{orderID: OrderId}) 
MATCH(user)-[acc:ORDERED]->(order)
SET acc.field1=field1,
acc.field2=field2;
```

But this query is taking too much time to execute, 
I even tried USING index on user and order node.

```
MATCH (user:User{userID: USERID}) USING INDEX user:User(userID)
```

Isn't it possible to create new attributes for the relationship at a later point? 
Please let me know, how can I do this operation in a quick and efficient way.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have created indexes on :User(userID) and :Order(orderID)? Without those indexes, USING INDEX will not improve this at all (it would still be a node by label scan, which would be impacted by the amount of data you've got), though it will still run without an error.

Comment: Perhaps you can turn that into an answer @InverseFalcon ?

Comment: Yeah, I have created constraints and they are ONLINE as well. I checked those before running this.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing everything right so far. It may be worth doing a single update with PROFILE and adding that to your description, that may give us some additional clues.

Answer (score 1):

You also forgot to prefix your query with USING PERIODIC COMMIT,

your query will build up transaction state for 24 million changes (property updates) and won't have enough memory to keep all that state.

You also forgot `row.` for the data that comes from your CSV and those names are inconsistently spelled.

If you run this from neo4j browser pay attention to any *YELLOW* warning signs.

#### Run

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.userID IS UNIQUE;
```

#### Run

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (o:Order) ASSERT o.orderID IS UNIQUE;
```

#### Run

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///FileName.csv' AS row
with row.USERID as userID, row.OrderId as orderID
MATCH (user:User{userID: userID})
USING INDEX user:User(userID)
MATCH (order:Order{orderID: orderID}) 
USING INDEX order:Order(orderID)
MATCH(user)-[acc:ORDERED]->(order)
SET acc.field1=row.field1, acc.field2=row.field2;
```

Comment: I used periodic commit and Constraints are ONLINE as well. Still its taking too much time.